# MATLAB: Matrix of pairwise differences

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a Nx1 vector of values. What I would like to do is create a NxN matrix where each value represents the difference between the ith and jth value - sort of like a large correlation matrix. I've done with this with a loop but I'm looking for a more elegant way to approach using MATLAB's vectorization capabilities as this vector may get quite large.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

what about

```
    diff__ = bsxfun(@minus,repmat(A,N,1),A');
```

which can be **definitely improved** by doing

```
    diff__ = bsxfun(@minus,A,A');
```

?

A little performance check:

```
   N = 1000;
   v = rand(N,1);

   tic
   diff__ = bsxfun(@minus,repmat(v,N,1),v');
   toc

   tic
   diff__ = bsxfun(@minus,v,v');
   toc
```

result

```
  Elapsed time is 105.343344 seconds.
  Elapsed time is 1.124946 seconds.
```

(Tim's data check:

diff__ =

```
 0     2     6     4
-2     0     4     2
-6    -4     0    -2
-4    -2     2     0
```

).

Comment: Faster than Tim's method testing with a 1000 element vector.

Answer (score 7):

`meshgrid` can generate matrices fit for this purpose. Obtain the difference matrix with

```
meshgrid(v) - meshgrid(v)'
```

Example:

```
>> v = [1 3 7 5]

v =

     1     3     7     5

>> meshgrid(v)

ans =

     1     3     7     5
     1     3     7     5
     1     3     7     5
     1     3     7     5

>> meshgrid(v) - meshgrid(v)'

ans =

     0     2     6     4
    -2     0     4     2
    -6    -4     0    -2
    -4    -2     2     0

>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice answers given already. But to join in the fun, here is another way (using Tim data)

```
v=[1 3 7 5];
 cell2mat(arrayfun(@(i) (v(i)-v)',1:size(v,2), 'UniformOutput',false))
```

ans =

```
 0     2     6     4
-2     0     4     2
-6    -4     0    -2
-4    -2     2     0
```