# Subtraction two vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, subtraction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MATLAB: Matrix of differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422606/matlab-matrix-of-differences)

I am not sure how to word this question but I will do my best:

I have two vectors, `A` and `B`.

I want to subtract the all values in `A` by every individual value of `B`.

For example, all values in `A` are subtracted by the first value of `B`. Then the all values of `A` are subtracted by the second value of B, and so on.

The resultant matrix should be `length(A) x length(B)` and look something like this:

`Ans = [A - B(1); A - B(2); A - B(3); ....... ]`

Is there any way of doing this without a loop?

Comment: The linked duplicate is subtracting `A` from `A`. Subtracting `B` from `A` should be easy to figure out.

Comment: Yesterday I answered *Exactly* to the same question putting effort in it. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13422675/1714661).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line like @Memming and @Jonas says:

```
Result = bsxfun(@minus, a, b');
```

Comment: Thanks for he optimization. It is faster.

Answer (score 2):

```
a=[2 3 4];      %first take two vector a and b of any size
b=[5 6 5 7];
m=size(a);      % Then Calculate the size of the vectors
n=size(b);  
r1=a'*ones(n);  % replicate the vector a and b one can use **repmat** here for replication  
r2=ones(m)'*b;  % like **repmat(a',n)  &  repmat(b,m(end),1)**
Result=r1-r2

Result =

    -3    -4    -3    -5
    -2    -3    -2    -4
    -1    -2    -1    -3
```

Comment: @Memming ... and more memory efficient

Comment: bsxfun does not allow to use vars declared with `sym`..