# MATLAB pairwise differences in Nth dimension

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, difference, dimension

Say i have a N-Dimensional matrix `A` that can be of any size. For example:

```
A = rand([2,5,3]);
```

I want to calculate all possible pairwise differences between elements of the matrix, along a given dimension. For example, if i wanted to calculate the differences along dimension 3, a shortcut would be to create a matrix like so:

```
B = cat(3, A(:,:,2) - A(:,:,1), A(:,:,3) - A(:,:,1), A(:,:,3) - A(:,:,2));
```

However, i want this to be able to operate along any dimension, with a matrix of any size. So, ideally, i'd like to either create a function that takes in a matrix `A` and calculates all pairwise differences along dimension `DIM`, or find a builtin MATLAB function that does the same thing.

The [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) function seems like it could be useful, but it only calculates differences between adjacent elements, not all possible differences.

Doing my research on this issue, i have found a [couple](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/44782-pairwise-difference-between-values-of-a-vector) of [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422606/matlab-matrix-of-pairwise-differences) about getting all possible differences, but most of these are for items in a vector (and ignore the dimensionality issue). Does anyone know of a quick fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Specific Dimension Cases**

If you don't care about a general solution, for a `dim=3` case, it would be as simple as couple lines of code -

```
dim = 3
idx = fliplr(nchoosek(1:size(A,dim),2))
B = A(:,:,idx(:,1)) - A(:,:,idx(:,2))
```

You can move around those `idx(..)` to specific dimension positions, if you happen to know the dimension before-hand. So, let's say `dim = 4`, then just do -

```
B = A(:,:,:,idx(:,1)) - A(:,:,:,idx(:,2))
```

Or let's say `dim = 3`, but `A` is a `4D` array, then do -

```
B = A(:,:,idx(:,1),:) - A(:,:,idx(:,2),:)
```

---

**Generic Case**

For a `Nth dim` case, it seems you need to welcome a party of `reshapes` and `permutes` -

```
function out = pairwise_diff(A,dim)

%// New permuting dimensions
new_permute = [dim setdiff(1:ndims(A),dim)];

%// Permuted A and its 2D reshaped version
A_perm = permute(A,new_permute);
A_perm_2d = reshape(A_perm,size(A,dim),[]);

%// Get pairiwse indices for that dimension
N = size(A,dim);
[Y,X] = find(bsxfun(@gt,[1:N]',[1:N])); %//' OR fliplr(nchoosek(1:size(A,dim),2))

%// Get size of new permuted array that would have the length of 
%// first dimension equal to number of such pairwise combinations 
sz_A_perm = size(A_perm);
sz_A_perm(1) = numel(Y);

%// Get the paiwise differences; reshape to a multidimensiona array of same
%// number of dimensions as the input array
diff_mat = reshape(A_perm_2d(Y,:) - A_perm_2d(X,:),sz_A_perm);

%// Permute back to original dimension sequence as the final output
[~,return_permute] = sort(new_permute);
out = permute(diff_mat,return_permute);

return
```

So much for a generalization , huh!

Comment: That appears to work, can't speak for speed / transparency though. Thanks a bunch!